# Execute a script automatically through pbrun?

Tags: shell, shell-script, login, authentication

There is a Unix environment named `sftwrk01`, `uatwrk01`, `intwrk01` and some more

I need to check the logs in each environment everyday by login in as below (through pbsu which is a wrapper for pbrun):

```
$pbsu - sftwrk01  //this helps to login to sftwrk01
```

and then after login I check the logs.
The same process goes for a few more environments like `uatwrk01`, `intwrk01` etc.

Now I tried this:

```
$pbsu - sftwrk01 && cd var/can/log && ls -lrt
```

but this did not work because actually the statement `cd var/can/log && ls -lrt` was being executed after I exited from the sftwrk01 environment by typing `exit`.

What could be the different possible solutions considering I don't have administrator rights? (i.e I am just one of the users in the home directory.)

If this is not possible without administrator rights then you can mention a way you could do it with having full permission (perhaps you would edit the some `.profile` file to do that)

```
**OS Info :**
rcihp145 :/home/msingh2> uname -a
HP-UX rcihp145 B.11.23 U 9000/800 3683851961 unlimited-user license
```

Other info:

```
 rcihp145 :/home/msingh2> ls -lrta
 total 7296
-r--r--r--   1 msingh2    users          438 Dec 22  2010 .profile
 drw-------   2 msingh2    users           96 Dec 22  2010 .ssh
-r--r--r--   1 msingh2    users          831 Dec 22  2010 .cshrc
-r--r--r--   1 msingh2    users          347 Dec 22  2010 .exrc
-r--r--r--   1 msingh2    users          333 Dec 22  2010 .login
 -rw-------   1 msingh2    users           56 Dec 23  2010 .sh_history.
-rwxr-xr-x   1 msingh2    users         5451 Dec 23  2010 .dtprofile
 -rw-------   1 msingh2    users      3577932 May 18 05:21 core
drwxr-xr-x  422 root       root         16384 Aug  3 14:27 ..
-rw-------   1 msingh2    users          245 Aug  4 00:41 .Xauthority
-rw-------   1 msingh2    users         1768 Aug  4 00:41 .TTauthority
drwxr-xr-x   4 msingh2    users         8192 Aug  4 00:41 .
 -rw-------   1 msingh2    users        37533 Aug  4 00:41 .ICEauthority
 -rw-------   1 msingh2    users         4064 Aug  4 06:28 .sh_history
 drwxr-xr-x  12 msingh2    users         8192 Aug  4 06:28 .dt
 -rw-------   1 msingh2    users         3462 Aug  5 02:29 .sh_history.msingh2
```

[here](http://ideone.com/o4Izk) is pbsu

Comment: Are you able/willing to modify your `pbsu` script?

Comment: pbrun is actually _designed_ to do what you want. The problem is that your pbsu script wraps it in an inconvenient way.

Comment: thanks but I dont want to modify that(pbsu) either

Comment: Unfortunately, the way that `pbsu` script is written, you would have to do either (modify `.profile` or `pbsu`).

Comment: Soory for trouble people... I seem to be putting a lot of restriction to do this... but even I have very restricted authorisation while working... so I wanted to find some unique way to do my work faster and easier way without logging into each account and then logging out and then logging in again to anohter one just to do some simple checks...(annoying)...!! I thought I could atomate it

Comment: But you **can** actually download a copy of `pbsu` to your home folder, right? You can then just modify *your own* `pbsu` script, possibly renaming it to sth. like `my_pbsu`. Then you'd just run `./my_pbsu <the_rest_as_described>` from your home directory.

Comment: yes I can do it

Comment: hmm...thanks :) i have to try that tommorrow ..it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if the server shell you are logging into is the original Korn Shell, but if so, you can modify the end of `pbsu` script so that

```
   [ -n "$REMOTEHOST" ] && /usr/local/bin/pbrun -h $REMOTEHOST -u $USERNAME /usr/local/bin/pbksh $LOGIN_SWITCH
   [ -n "$REMOTEHOST" ] || /usr/local/bin/pbrun -b -u $USERNAME /usr/local/bin/pbksh $LOGIN_SWITCH
```

becomes

```
   [ -n "$REMOTEHOST" ] && /usr/local/bin/pbrun -h $REMOTEHOST -u $USERNAME /usr/local/bin/pbksh $LOGIN_SWITCH ${@:2}
   [ -n "$REMOTEHOST" ] || /usr/local/bin/pbrun -b -u $USERNAME /usr/local/bin/pbksh $LOGIN_SWITCH ${@:2}
```

.

Then you'd be able to just send commands to the server without logging into the shell, using

```
pbsu - sftwrk01 -c "your commands here"
```

(Mind the quotes!) So, for your example, it would be

```
pbsu - sftwrk01 -c "ls -lrt var/can/log"
```

(Notice, by the way, that you don't need to change to some directory to list its contents - just give the name of that directory to the `ls` command, as shown above.)

Comment: +1 for the info @rozcietrzewiacz I guess this is the only possible way(apart from editing the .profile) as told by you.+1 to the answer also...thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem :) And thanks for accepting in spite of all!